# Passing Networking Commands through RUST Programs

Tags: windows, networking, rust, network-programming, command

I had a syntax issue regarding the running of Windows cmd commands through rust program. I want to pass tis command:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Adapter123" static 192.0.0.4 255.255.255.0 192.0.0.4
```

> (Syntax: netsh interface ipv4 set address name="YOUR INTERFACE NAME" static IP_ADDRESS SUBNET_MASK GATEWAY)

I kept running into syntax error while running the Rust program i have written below. what is the error in the syntax and how to write the code syntax for the command above?

```
use std::process::Command;
fn main()
{
Command::new("netsh")
.arg(&["interface", "ipv4","set","address","name = ",
"Adapter123","static", "192.0.0.4", "255.255.255.0", "192.0.0.4"])
.spawn()
.expect("ls command failed to start");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the following: You seem to have forgotten to add an 's' to one of your functions.

```rust
use std::process::Command;

pub fn main() {
    Command::new("netsh")
        .args(&["interface", "ipv4","set","address","name = ",
        "Adapter123","static", "192.0.0.4", "255.255.255.0", "192.0.0.4"])
        .spawn()
        .expect("ls command failed to start");
}
```

I changed the following:

```rust
.arg(...)
```

to

```rust
.args(...)
```

[The method `.arg()` expects a **single** argument to add to its arguments](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.arg)
You want to add **multiple** arguments to the command, therefore, you have to use the [`.args()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.args), which expects an (in this case) array.

The args method just does the following:

```rust
for arg in args {
    self.arg(args.as_ref());
}
```

Good luck with whatever you are building!

Comment: I get a new error.  Syntax supplied for this command is not valid. Check help for the correct syntax.

Usage: set address [name=]<string>
             [[source=]dhcp|static]
             [[address=]<IPv4 address>[/<integer>] [[mask=]<IPv4 mask>]
             [[gateway=]<IPv4 address>|none [gwmetric=]<integer>]
             [[type=]unicast|anycast]
             [[subinterface=]<string>]
             [[store=]active|persistent]  Examples:

       set address name="Wired Ethernet Connection" source=dhcp
       set address "Wired Ethernet Connection" static 10.0.0.9 255.0.0.0 10.0.0.1 1